# Change git branch in terminal without changing in eclipse and vice versa

Tags: eclipse, git, github

How can we change switch branches on a terminal without switching the same on an IDE (say eclipse in my case)

I have a branch b1 which is currently on terminal. Open eclipse and see the same branch of code.

After a particular point, if I change the branch in terminal, say checkout b2, even eclipse is getting changed to b2 which should not be the case.

Comment: If the terminal and the IDE refer to the same work tree, it's almost impossible. But as I know, after you checkout branch2, the IDE is expected to prompt a dialogue to ask if you want to update the files. You could press No to keep its original contents.

Comment: Yes, they refer to the same work tree.

Comment: As ElpieKay pointed out, it's almost impossible, since a git branch checkout changes the files in your directory. Since Eclipse sees those sames files, it will try to update them, or if you don't, I guess you'll end up with lots of swap files that you'll have to find a way to organize. Maybe keep two git directories, of the same repository though, and be mindful about committing, pushing and pulling in both?

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround (especially if your `.project` is not versioned) is to:

- have multiple working tree (one for `b1`, one for `b2` in their own respective folders)
  It is possible since [git 2.5 and the `git worktree add` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309);
- have a `.project` with different name in them like `project_b1` and `project_b2`.

That way, you can actually import `project_b1` and `project_b2` in the Eclipse workspace, and you can work/compile concurrently on both projects.